# How to trim and center an object on the canvas keeping the background?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

Having input images like that

[image: Input]

I need to

- trim to a ratio of 3:4,
- place the person in the center of that 3:4 canvas, and
- keep the background.

That's the desired output I would need:

[image: Desired output]

This is the code I have so far. It crops the edges of the model, but I need it to place it onto a canvas of 3:4 keeping the backround colour.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#img = cv2.imread("test.png")
img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200)

## find the non-zero min-max coords of canny
pts = np.argwhere(canny>0)
y1,x1 = pts.min(axis=0)
y2,x2 = pts.max(axis=0)

## crop the region
cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropped)

tagged = cv2.rectangle(img.copy(), (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("tagged", tagged)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following solution, I assumed

1. input images to have white-ish background,
2. cutouts are made using the whole height of the image, and
3. there's enough space around the person to get a proper 3:4 cutout.

The procedure is quite simple:

1. Resize image such that height is a multiple of 4 to get an exact 3:4 cutout.
2. Inverse binarize the grayscaled image to mask the person.
3. Get the bounding rectangle of the person.
4. Calculate the horizontal center of the bounding rectangle, and the desired width from the height.
5. Slice the image from "center - 0.5 * width" to "center + 0.5 * width".

That'd be the full code:

```py
import cv2

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('qUgOO.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Resize such that height is a multiple of 4
th = h & (-4)
tw = int((th / h) * w)
img = cv2.resize(img, (tw, th))

# Get bounding rectangle of person (assuming white-ish background)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 192, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
bx, by, bw, bh = cv2.boundingRect(thr)

# Create 3:4 cutout around center of bounding rectangle of person
cx = bx + bw // 2
tw = int(th * (3 / 4))
l = int(cx - (1 / 2) * tw)
out = img[:, l:l+tw]
print(out.shape[1] / out.shape[0])
# 0.75
```

The resulting image looks pretty much the same as your desired output.

Regarding the assumption made:

1. If you have different backgrounds, especially dark ones, you need to adapt the finding of the bounding rectangle of the person.
2. If cutouts should also take height into account (i.e. head of person is below upper image border), you'd need to also calculate the vertical center of the bounding rectangle.
3. If persons can be at the very left or right side of an image, you need to check whether the final slicing might violate image dimensions, and correct accordingly.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.2
OpenCV:        4.5.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: a lot of logic in just few lines of code ! Thank you very much !